# What do these things have in common? Please answer in the form of a mushroom

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> A thug like blood line
>
> A less wild long night
>
> A half high boat saver

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71/gilles

Comment: @Randal'Thor and now someone must never change there profile picture.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer is...

> [image] OP:[image: A Proper Life Mushroom]

Which is a...

> [Life mushroom!](https://www.mariowiki.com/Life_Mushroom)

And the common thread is...

> all the words combine with "life" to make another word/phrase:
>
>  A thug(life) (life)like (life)blood (life)line
>  A (life)less wild(life) (life)long night(life)
>  A half(life) high(life) (life)boat (life)saver

Comment: Given your transformation of the verse, I really want a proper fourth line conclusion, because it just falls into 3 groups of a standard 4/4 rhythm

Comment: @CAD97: A second time raft pro? ;)

Comment: Do the phrases in the modified riddle mean anything? They seem nonsensical.

Comment: @jpmc26: The new phrases don't make sense, but the original phrases didn't either. The point is that each individual word can be combined with "life" to make another word. (With a bit of artistic licence, you can make "alive" from "a".)

Comment: @gnovice You got it.

Comment: @Jpmc26 It's just as MOehm said, the 'phrases' were basically meaningless and were just put there to hide the simple word association puzzle.

Answer (score 13):

Let's try this :

> **A mold with five words**

Because

> All of your sentences have the same pattern (come from the same *mold*), as "A xxxx yyyy aaaa(a) bbbb(b)", with xxxx and yyyy being four letters long and aaaa(a) and bbbb(b) being 4 and 5 letters long in whichever order.

And also

> *Mold* is a kind of mushroom!

Comment: This is a good, inventive, lateral fit that's simple enough to explain and understand...  But no.  The words used matter beyond the total words and characters per line. +1 though.  And I'll award an extra big, extra shiny +1 if someone gets the right answer in the form of a picture. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is (and this is *probably* a bit of a stretch)

> Hyphen

Or, in picture form

> [image]

Because

> Each phrase is missing a hyphen. Hyphen (hyphae in English, all I could find to link this is the German translation which is Hyphen) is a part of mycelium. (I don't know much about growing mushrooms!)
>
>  A thug **-** like blood line
>  A less **-** wild long night (Not as sure about this line, really.)
>  A half **-** high boat saver

Comment: Someone did some homework at least... +1 for effort :)

Comment: A couple of hours of homework. ;) And given the answer, I'm kicking myself. I would've known that one if I didn't overthink it! xD Great puzzle!